# SwiftUI/Xcode Build issue

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xcode-build-settings

I am not sure why this is happening.  My project was building and now it is not.  I am getting the following error.

Showing All Errors Only
'/Users/brandonaho/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SimplyMocktails-fwegyymiduaweqcvzgkqccptvxmc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/SimplyMocktails.app/onboarding4.json' is longer than filepath buffer size (1025).

I can't seem to figure out why there is so many nested paths in there.  I have removed the file and re-added it to the Build Phases>Copy Bundle Resources.

I have cleaned out my build directory restarted everything and still no luck.  I haven't a clue on where the multiple nested directory path would be coming from.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This has been resolved.